# Find the Exact value of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^{\pi} e^{-nx}\sin (kx) dx$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

> Find the Exact value of :
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^{\pi} e^{-nx}\sin (kx) dx$$

---

What I did :

Take $I=\int_0^{\pi}e^{-nx}\sin(kx)dx$

After Integration, I get $$I=\frac{k(1-e^{-n\pi}\cos(k\pi))}{n^2+k^2}$$

But that's the end.

I don't have any ideas to sqeeze this, And I can't change this to integrals because of $n$ which stand on exponential.

Did I miss something during calculating $I$?

Comment: This may look like a Riemann sum to me

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.**

So you have found 
$$I_k=\frac{k}{k^2+n^2}-e^{-n\pi}\cdot \frac{\cos(k\pi)}{k^2+n^2}$$
The first one can be written as
$$\frac{k}{k^2+n^2}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{k/n}{1+(k/n)^2}$$
which gives you a Riemann sum after taking the sum.

Bound the second term as follows
$$\left|e^{-n\pi}\frac{\cos(k\pi)}{k^2+n^2}\right|\leq e^{-n\pi}$$
which gives you what after taking the sum...? Can you conclude?

Comment: If you bound the second term, how is this the exact sum?

Comment: @eranreches Do you know what you get after taking the sum? The sum of the second terms in absolute value, is bounded by $$\sum_{k=1}^n e^{-n\pi}$$ is what I claim. Do you know what that sum evaluates to?

Comment: Ohh you're right. I missed the fact that $n$ is both in the exponent and in the sum. I will delete my comment and +1 for your answer.